# Spring session schema for sybase jdbc not working

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, sybase, spring-session

Am using the sybase schema file provided in spring session documentation. But I still face incorrect syntax near "ON". So delete cascade is not working for the SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES table.Due to which am unable to delete the records of below table.Below is the contents from schema file. Am executing this in SqlDbx.

```
CREATE TABLE SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES (
    SESSION_PRIMARY_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    ATTRIBUTE_NAME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    ATTRIBUTE_BYTES IMAGE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_PK PRIMARY KEY (SESSION_PRIMARY_ID, ATTRIBUTE_NAME),
    CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_FK FOREIGN KEY (SESSION_PRIMARY_ID) REFERENCES SPRING_SESSION(PRIMARY_ID)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    )LOCK DATAROWS
```

Any suggestions to fix this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the foreign key constraint and delete cascade from the sql. And add delete trigger on SPRING_SESSION. Executed the below code in sybase db.

```
CREATE TABLE SPRING_SESSION (
    PRIMARY_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    SESSION_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    CREATION_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL,
    LAST_ACCESS_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL,
    MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL INT NOT NULL,
    EXPIRY_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRINCIPAL_NAME VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_PK PRIMARY KEY (PRIMARY_ID)
) LOCK DATAROWS

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SPRING_SESSION_IX1 ON SPRING_SESSION (SESSION_ID)
CREATE INDEX SPRING_SESSION_IX2 ON SPRING_SESSION (EXPIRY_TIME)
CREATE INDEX SPRING_SESSION_IX3 ON SPRING_SESSION (PRINCIPAL_NAME)
```

Trigger to delete

```
create trigger delcascadetrig 
on SPRING_SESSION 
for delete 
as 
delete SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES
from SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES, deleted 
where SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES.SESSION_PRIMARY_ID = deleted.PRIMARY_ID
```

This helped me to solve the issue.